# Split Xml into multiple files using xslt: Failed to transform document Exception: Could not find function: current-group

Tags: xslt-2.0

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Objects">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="business">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="WorkItem" group-starting-with="WorkItem[(position() -1)mod 3 = 0]">
      <xsl:variable name="file" select="concat('WorkItem',position(),'.xml')"/>
      <xsl:result-document href="{$file}">
        <Objects>
          <business>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
          </business>
        </Objects>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

InputXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
  <Objects>
    <business>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
  </business>
</Objects>
```

Expected Output: 2 separate files with three Workitems in each.

Error received:

```
Error: XSLT Service failed. Failed to transform document Exception:   
  javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: current-group
```

Comment: Input file:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
    <Objects>
    </business>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    <WorkItem>
    ..............
    </WorkItem>
    </business>
    <Objects>

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheet uses XSLT 2.0 features but you are running it using an XSLT 1.0 processor.